# Populating '<select>' Dynamically and Retrieving Seleceted Value

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello i populated a drop down list with data from the database, now i want to retrieve the selected value and echo it but itz not working, it keeps on coming up empty.

```
<select>
   <option value="0">--None Selected--</option>
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'Phil';
$dbpass = '********';

// Fetching UserGroupID int TextBox
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM   usergroups";
mysql_select_db('dopetunez');


$result = mysql_query($sql);

// While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
// Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop
// Note: If you put extract($row); inside the following loop, you'll
//  then create $userid, $fullname, and $userstatus

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  

?>

<option value="<?php echo $row["UserGroupID"] ?>"> <?php echo $row["UserGroup"]?>
</option>

<?php
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: I hope the code is readable.

Comment: Ps: I'm new to PHP.  I mostly do ASP.NET

Comment: please dont use mysql_* function those are deprecated see this http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189

Answer (score 1):

At first glance ..
you should select db before executing the query .. so replace

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM   usergroups";
 mysql_select_db('dopetunez');
```

with

```
  mysql_select_db('dopetunez');
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM   usergroups";
```

**SUGGESTION** please use [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)  . mysql_ are no longer maintained

Comment: The query isn't getting executed until after a database is selected

Comment: Try capturing error using `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())`

Comment: Okay i'll do that but how do i get the selected 'value' not 'text' in the drop down?

Comment: @GolDRoger replace `<?php echo $row["UserGroup"]?>` with `<?php echo $row["UserGroupID"]?>` in option . This is what you need I suppose ..

Comment: But then wont it display the UserGroupID instead? I want for it to display the UserGroup but have a value of the UserGroupID.

Comment: Okay thanx i made the necessary changes and it looks like i forgot to add the 'name'to the select tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should select Database first. Then only you can access queries. Please change like this,

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db('dopetunez');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM   usergroups";
```

Comment: The query isn't getting executed until after a database is selected